# About decay of Fourier coefficients of "almost" $C^2$ functions.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

If a function is $C^2$ outside a measure zero set in its domain then do its Fourier coeffients still decay as $O(\frac{1}{k^2})$ ? Assume that the function is continuous but not differentiable on that measure-zero set.

Answer (score 2):

No. For example, consider $f(x)=\sqrt{|x|}$ on the interval $[-\pi, \pi]$. The cosine coefficients are
$$
A_n = \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^{\pi} \sqrt{x}\cos nx\,dx = -\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{\operatorname{Si}(\sqrt{2n})}{n^{3/2}}
$$
according to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+cos(n*x)*sqrt(x)+from+0+to+pi).  Since the [sine integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral) has a nonzero limit at infinity, the size of $A_n$ is $\sim 1/n^{3/2}$.

I also expect  that $f(x)=|x|^p$ has cosine coefficients $\sim 1/n^{1+p}$ for $0<p<1$, but do not have a proof.

Comment: Thanks. Any intuitive way to see why just a single point of non-differentiability is able to violate the general theorem?

Comment: Consider piecewise constant functions: why does a single point of discontinuity make the coefficients so large? Because there is a boundary term from integration by parts there. With the discontinuity of the derivative it's the same thing one level below.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any general theorem about this? As to what would the decay rate of Fourier coefficients be if a function is continuous everywhere but not differentiable on a measure 0 set and is $C^k$ outside this measure 0 set?

Comment: $C^k$ makes no difference. $\sqrt{|x|}$ is infinitely differentiable outside a one-point set.  I don't think there is a theorem for "smooth except a small set" functions because as we see here, that small set trumps smoothness. To prove a theorem, one has to make some assumptions that actually matter to the size of coefficients.